Why do secularists believe Deuteronomy was written during the reign of King Josiah?
While we're at it, why do they believe it was written by many different sources? I am reading the book JEWS, GOD, AND HISTORY by Max Dimont where he goes into greater detail about this. Also, what are the refutations to these claims?

Doesn't the book provide an answer for the why?

related/duplicate: Where can I find responses to biblical criticism?
